# vscode does not show typescript error (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

When I open the ts source in a angular project via vscode,there is no error message.

```
let toolbox = {
  'show': true,
  'feature': {}
};
if (saveAsImage) Object.assign(toolbox.feature, { saveAsImage: {} });
if (restore) toolbox.feature['restore'] = {};
```

But when I copy this source file(only this ts source file) to other place and open it via vscode,the error message comes.

```
if (restore) toolbox.feature['restore'] = {};
```

If I need to modify angular config file to switch on error message or modify vscode config file?

typescript version 3.9.5

angular version 10.0.2